# Failure to download spacy model

Tags: python, spacy

how do I fix the below error while downloading a spacy model

'C:\Users\Paul' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Can you show us the command you're running? My guess is that there's a space in your username when you are putting in `C:\path\to\some\executable`

Comment: # download models and data for the English language:
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m spacy download en

Comment: I'm not sure where that's valid syntax. Can you provide full context *in the question* please?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a path with a space in it and are using an iPython notebook on Windows. You should run your command like this:

```
!"{sys.executable}" -m spacy download en
```

Also it looks like you might be using spaCy v2, I would strongly suggest using v3 at this point.